# Show gene names on heatmap

Tags: r

here is my script:

```
heatmap.2(
as.matrix(data[,2:7]), 
trace="none",
dendrogram="row", 
cexRow=0.5, cexCol=0.95,
)
```

The gene names appear as numbers as I excluded the first column that contains gene names. 
How can I replace the numbering by gene names?

Many thanks

Comment: If you could provide a sample of the data with `dput` so we could experiment I am certain the problem would be resolved much faster. [Suggested reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

if you have a matrix object (named m) and a vector of genes (named g), you can add row names like this:

```
rownames(m) <- g
```

you can similarly add the names of columns:

```
colnames(m) <- vector
```

then you can re-plot the heatmap of matrix m

Hope this helps. Cheers!